# Find the set of points of a curve with shortest distance to a point

Tags: optimization, curves

**How to find the set of points of to the curve $y^2=x^3+3x^2+x+1$ with the shortest distance to the point $(0,0)$**

I try this:

$$d=\sqrt{x^2 + (x^3+3x^2+x+1)^2}$$
$$\frac{dd}{dx}= \frac{2x+2(x^3+3x^2+x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + (x^3+3x^2+x+1)^2}}=0$$

And now I would take the real solutions and substitute in $d$ to get the minimum distance from $(0,0)$ to the curve. But I'd have two problems; The only real solution is negative, and i would not be finding the closest points of the curve to my point, but only the minimum distance to one of them.

Comment: A general tip: finding the shortest distance is the same as finding the square of the shortest distance. $d^2$ is much easier to differentiate than $d$!

Comment: If you have a solution for $x$ then the $y$-coordinate of the point is $\pm\sqrt{x^3+3x^2+x+1}$

Comment: Is it $y^2=x^3+3x^2+x+1$ or $y=x^3+3x^2+x+1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider $$d^2=x^3+4x^2+x+1=g(x)$$ then we get
$$g'(x)=3x^2+8x+1$$ and you must solve the equation $$g'(x)=0$$